# MATLAB 'isbetween' function erases itself in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to create a logical array of when dates fall in between two Fridays. The loop below works on the first pass, but then when i=2, the previous logical 1s are erased (i.e. turn to 0). The second set of logical 1s then come up, but I need all of them, not just one iteration. I'd be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks.

```
for i = 1:length(secondFriday)
    between=isbetween(vifDate,secondFriday(i)+1,thirdFriday(i));
end
```

Comment: use `between(i,:)=isbetween(vifDate,secondFriday(i)+1,thirdFriday(i));` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Gnimuc Key, thanks, I was able to figure this out with your help.

```
for i = 1:length(secondFriday)
    between(:,i)=isbetween(vifDate,secondFriday(i)+1,thirdFriday(i));
end

between=sum(between,2);
```